# Creating a batch file that runs a Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, exe

I want to run this as a batch rather than through the command line:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:bigben.cac.washington.edu /syncfromflags:MANUAL
net stop w32time & net start w32time
w32tm /resync
```

Comment: is the question how to create a .bat file?  if so, just use notepad and save it as filename.bat.

Comment: But don't I have to do something else to make it run this in the command prompt?

Comment: just put this line in notepad, save it as a .bat file.  then when you double click on it, windows will launch a command prompt and fire the command.  you can add an echo statement to give some kind of return to you when it is completed.  you can also put "pause" on the next line of the bat file and the command window will stay open after completing.  I think a /k switch at the end of the line does the same.

Comment: the only thing that might be needed is a path or environment variable set so the command prompt knows where the w32tm command lives

Comment: Aaron: Are you asking if you need to flag the batch file to make it executable?  In windows batch, it is by default executable.  In linux, for instance, you need to chmod it to be able to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that you are just trying to execute these commands one after another in a batch file?

If so you need to open `notepad`.

Copy and paste your commands into notepad as you have in your question and click `File -> Save As`.

Give the file a name i.e. `MyBatchFile.bat`. Underneath the filename box change the file type to `All Files`. The `.bat` on the end of the filename will instruct the PC to open it as a batch file.

Batch files by default open with Command Prompt so all you will have to do is run it.